# How to import a CSV file when its name contains dots?

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I need to import .csv files via script from a read-only directory to an Access table.

It fails for files with dots in the name: e.g. *fi.le.name.csv*.

I found these solutions:

1. rename the file
2. copy the file and give it a name without dots

Is it possible to solve it differently?

```vb
Dim strSelect as String
Dim strFile as String 
Dim strConnectionString as String
Dim strFolder as String
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

strFolder = "C:\path"

strConnectionString = "Provider=" & _
  CurrentProject.Connection.Provider & _
  ";Data Source=" & strFolder & Chr(92) & _
  ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"

cn.Open strConnectionString

strFile = "fi.le.name.csv"
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM " & strFile

rs.Open strSelect, cn, adOpenForwardonly 'and here is the failure
```

Comment: Need to declare rs and cn variables - you Set rn but Open rs. Can set a link to CSV file and work with the linked table to pull data into local table.

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit in module header? It will help you catch spelling errors with variable names.

Comment: Yes, I have. Sorry for the mistakes, I was retyping part of my code from another system which is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried use shortname, it's working for me:

```
    Sub dots()
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    strFolder = "c:\Users\Alex20\Documents" ' my path
    
    strConnectionString = "Provider=" & _
    "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" & _
    ";Data Source=" & strFolder & _
    "\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
    
    'Debug.Print strConnectionString
    
    cn.Open strConnectionString
    
    strFile = "fi.le.name.csv"
    strFile = ShortName(strFile)
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM `" & strFile & "`"
    
    Debug.Print strSelect   'SELECT * FROM `FILENA~1.CSV`
    rs.Open strSelect, cn, adOpenForwardonly 'and here is the failure
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub

Function ShortName(filespec)
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    ShortName = f.ShortName
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexej. I will use your solution.

Comment: The file path 'filespec' for 'ShortName' function needs to be full path, not only the name of the file, in other case it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to another folder and rename it by deleting the dot. The connection syntax is also specified in another folder.

```
Sub test()
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strTarget As String
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    strFolder = "C:\path"
    strTarget = "C:\"
    
    strConnectionString = "Provider=" & _
    "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" & _
    ";Data Source=" & strTarget & Chr(92) & _
    ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
    
    cn.Open strConnectionString
    
    strFile = "fi.le.name.csv" 
    Dim vF As Variant, newFile As String
    
    vF = Split(strFile, ".")
    newFile = Replace(strFile, vF(UBound(vF)), "")
    newFile = Replace(newFile, ".", "") & "." & vF(UBound(vF))
    
    FileCopy strFolder & "\" & strFile, strTarget & newFile
    
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM " & newFile
    
    rs.Open strSelect, cn 'and here is the failure
    
    Debug.Print rs(0)
  
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think Excel is involved so CopyFromRecordset is not relevant. Use a `Debug.Print rs(0)` to test. Tested your version and get same error.

Comment: @june7, ok, i misunderstand.